# I changed my Wordpress theme folder. Now it's not finding my stylesheet after I changed it back

Tags: wordpress, sass, themes

I hope this is a quick fix, but I've been searching for a solution and haven't found one.

Quick background:
I've been developing my Wordpress website locally using `WAMP`. I'm getting the site ready to deploy to a production server, and before deploying it I wanted to simply rename my theme folder from "naked-wordpress-master" to "My Portfolio" or something different.

First, I went to my theme folder and changed the name. I refreshed the Appearance > Themes page in the `wp-admin` site and got an error that the stylesheet could not be found.

I got a bit worried, so what I did next was rename the theme folder back to "naked-wordpress-master" and refresh the page. Same error.

I then tried deleting the theme from the `wp-admin` site and re-uploading it. I got an error the upload failed because the stylesheet couldn't be found.

FYI I'm using `SCSS` that outputs a `style.min.css`, but that shouldn't matter. I didn't change anything else from the header, functions.php, or stylesheet linking and it was all working just fine before.

Any ideas on what's going wrong and why my stlyesheet is failing to get recognized?

Thanks a bunch.

--Update--
I'm noticing my index.php loads fine, [but sub-pages look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hQLN.png)

Comment: In your database find the "_options table (table prefix could be what ever you have set while installing wordpress). In options table, find the entries for "template" and "stylesheet" (both are different entries) and check their corresponding values. That will give some idea on further troubleshooting.

Comment: I went to my database and saw the values of the template and stylesheet. It looks like they fell back to a previous theme when I deactivated my original theme and tried to upload it again. I then manually changed them in the database back to "naked-wordpress-master" hoping that'd fix the problem. When I went back to my wp-admin > themes page my theme is now "naked-wordpress-master" (which is good) but it's still saying "ERROR: Stylesheet is missing"

Comment: Well, just to be sure, can check if there is actually "style.css" in the root location of your theme?

Comment: My "style.min.css" file and "style.scss" files are in a css folder inside the root. This didn't seem to cause an issue before so I'm wondering why it is now? Just to test it, I added a blank style.css file inside the root and the theme seems to have loaded fine, but I'd like to point back to my "style.min.css" file in my css folder like before if possible.

Comment: You can enqueue your "style.min.css" via functions.php file of your theme. So, the blank "style.css" will remain just as placeholder (say, for technical requirement) and your "style.min.css" will still work for you.

Comment: I'm already enqueuing my "style.min.css" from my functions.php - "wp_enqueue_style('style.css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/style.min.css');". What's interesting is my index.php looks fine, but all other sub-pages have zero styling.

Comment: Can you check if your "style.min.css" is actually getting applied for the sub-pages?

Comment: Please see updated screenshot in the bottom of the post. It looks like it's not even loading my page, let alone the css...

Comment: Well, doesn't even look like your website's page. It looks like WAMP page. Can you check if your .htaccess file exists?

Comment: Is it supposed to be in my theme folder? Because I found it in my wordpress folder (I'm sorry I'm a designer not a developer, so these are new concepts for me!). You can google chat me if you'd like at capokrzywa@gmail.com

Comment: .htaccess file resides in the root location of your wordpress installation folder. It is not supposed to be a file in your theme. Try doing this. In admin are, go to settings->permalinks, change the permalinks settings to something different, save the settings and revert back to what ever you had set before. This flush the permalink rules and also create the .htaccess file if its missing.

Comment: You're a savior! Thank you. That seemed to work. Can I give you credit somehow?

Comment: That fact that I was able to help you is good enough for me. I am glad that your problem is solved. Still, for the sake of other readers, I will try and summarise our comments into a comprehensible answer to your question. You can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your database find the `"_options` table (table prefix could be what ever you have set while installing wordpress). In options table, find the entries for "template" and "stylesheet" (both are different entries) and check their corresponding values. If that is not your theme name, change it manually to your theme name.

Also, make sure your theme has `style.css` at its root location. That's a technical requirement for enabling the theme.

**After Update**

Seems like its a rewrite issue. Check if the .htaccess file exists.

If it doesn't, in admin are, go to settings->permalinks, change the permalinks settings to something different, save the settings and revert back to what ever you had set before. (Ideally you should select the "post name" setting, which generates pretty permalinks which are also SEO friendly)

This will flush the permalink rules and also create the .htaccess file if its missing.

Hope this helps.